# Make a window and alter the pixels directly

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, window, game-engine

I have been looking into OpenGL and c++ with the intention to perhaps make some kind of graphics.

I have looked into some OpenGL stuff but I feel like there's a lot of functions where unknown stuff happens.

What would be the best way to get a window up and running where I could freely alter each pixel and then put that on the screen?

Then I could make some math stuff behind the scenes that change that raster and thereby what you see on the screen.

Do anyone have an idea on how to implement this in c++ and what I should be using to do so?

If there is any better way of achieving what I am searching I would like to hear so too.

Comment: I would say: [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com). That is the best starting point of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes I have already looked at OpenGL and that particular website, but do you know if open gl supports giving it a matrix with pixel data and then printing that to the screen

Comment: The thing is, OpenGL utilizes your videocard. If you tried to do the same things manually, it would happen entirely on CPU.

Comment: That said, take a look at [SDL2](http://libsdl.org/). Among other things, it lets you directly modify pixels. And when you're done practicing that, it can be used with OpenGL too.

Comment: Just presenting pixel data on the screen, SDL would suffice but if you want to modify the pixel data, the best approach for that would be to utilize the GPU. OpenGL is a good solution for that. I don't know what you mean by _some math stuff_, even if you use simple operations on the individual pixel data, the GPU will be much faster than the CPU, and as long the GPU does its work, the CPU can be used for other things.

Comment: But let's say i were to make some sort of ray traycing and I had the pixel data in a matrix of some kind. How would I display that on a screen. What software should I use.

Comment: @Christian: please don't use the term 'matrix' for images; the proper term is 'raster'. In computer graphics context 'matrix' refers to a linear (or bilinear) transformation applied to a vector space (usually 3x3 or 4x4); it's a misnomer to refer to rasters as matrices, popularized by some libraries like OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking so many questions at once, without realizing how complicated that topic is. Implementing a low-level graphics library is way more difficult than you realize. As some comments suggest, yes you should definitely follow the tutorials on learnopengl.com. They are very well-written and explain everything you need.

> What would be the best way to get a window up and running where I could freely alter the frames with a matrix that contained the information for each pixel and then put that on the screen.

This depends on a lot of aspects. You need to consider if you want this "matrix" to be stored on CPU memory or on GPU memory, because implementations of these two differ wildly. You can "draw stuff" on the GPU, then transfer that memory back to CPU memory (the "matrix" you mention"), modify it, and send it back for rendering. You can also have everything on GPU and then write a shader program to interpret the pixel information and output different colors.

Again, to warn you: Low-level graphics is a hugely complicated topic. If you are looking for an easy fix, you will not find it here.

If I understand your question correctly you will need to know about:

- OpenGL buffering (glBufferData)
- Framebuffers and color attachments
- Shader programming, compiling, linking, and loading.
- viewport size for the dimensions of your "matrix" (glViewport)

I suggest using the [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/) library for the window, they have clean interface and good documentation. You might also be able to use SDL - I don't have any experience with that, but you would still need to know what you are doing. From what I have learned so far, spending time learning the basics up-front is usually always worth it.